# Save SparseBooleanArray to SharedPreferences

Tags: android, performance, sharedpreferences, android-sqlite, sparse-array

For my app, I need to save a simple SparseBooleanArray to memory and read it later.
Is there any way to save it using SharedPreferences?

I considered using an SQLite database but it seemed overkill for something as simple as this. Some other answers I found on StackOverflow suggested using GSON for saving it as a String but I need to keep this app very light and fast in file size. Is there any way of achieving this without relying on a third party library and while maintaining good performance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the power of JSON to save in the shared preferences for any type of object

For example SparseIntArray 
Save items like Json string

```
public static void saveArrayPref(Context context, String prefKey, SparseIntArray intDict) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    JSONArray json = new JSONArray();
    StringBuffer data = new StringBuffer().append("[");
    for(int i = 0; i < intDict.size(); i++) {
        data.append("{")
                .append("\"key\": ")
                .append(intDict.keyAt(i)).append(",")
                .append("\"order\": ")
                .append(intDict.valueAt(i))
                .append("},");
        json.put(data);
    }
    data.append("]");
    editor.putString(prefKey, intDict.size() == 0 ? null : data.toString());
    editor.commit();
}
```

and read json string

```
public static SparseIntArray getArrayPref(Context context, String prefKey) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    String json = prefs.getString(prefKey, null);
    SparseIntArray intDict = new SparseIntArray();
    if (json != null) {
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject item = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                intDict.put(item.getInt("key"), item.getInt("order"));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return intDict;
}
```

and use like this:

```
    SparseIntArray myKeyList = new SparseIntArray(); 
    ...
    //write list
    saveArrayPref(getApplicationContext(),"MyList", myKeyList);
    ...
    //read list
    myKeyList = getArrayPref(getApplicationContext(), "MyList");
```

Comment: Clever! I like it!

Answer (score 3):

Write the values separately, and keep a list of the names of the values you write:

```
    SparseBooleanArray array = //your array;
    SharedPreferences prefs = //your preferences

    //write
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
    Set<String> keys = new HashSet<String>(array.size());
    for(int i = 0, z = array.size(); i < z; ++i) {
        int key = array.keyAt(i);
        keys.add(String.valueOf(key));
        edit.putBoolean("key_" + key, array.valueAt(i));
    }
    edit.putStringSet("keys", keys);
    edit.commit();

    //read
    Set<String> set = prefs.getStringSet("keys", null);
    if(set != null && !set.isEmpty()) {
        for (String key : set) {
            int k = Integer.parseInt(key);
            array.put(k, prefs.getBoolean("key_"+key, false));
        }
    }
```

String sets are supported since API 11.
You could instead build a single csv string and split that rather than storing the set.

Answer (score 1):

You can `serialize` the object to a byte array and then probably base64 the byte array before saving to SharedPreferences. Object serialization is really easy, you don't need a third party library for that.

```
public static byte[] serialize(Object obj) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOS = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream objectOS = new ObjectOutputStream(byteArrayOS);
    objectOS.writeObject(obj);
    objectOS.flush();
    return byteArrayOS.toByteArray();
}

public static Object deserialize(byte[] data) {
    ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayIS = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
    ObjectInputStream objectIS = new ObjectInputStream(byteArrayIS);
    return objectIS.readObject();
}
```

The code above doesn't have try catch block for simplicity. You can add it on your own.

Comment: How good is this regarding performance?
Also, I noticed that you're using a byte array for this. How should I save that byte array into the SharedPreferences if there is no method that allows that data type?

Comment: Any form of serialization is slow. However unless your object reaches megabytes or bigger, the delay is really very unnoticeable. As I understood, you need to save only one array. I guess it will be OK.

Comment: You need to base64 the byte array to turn it into a string before saving it. And then you need to de-base64 when reading it to get the byte array before deserializing.

Answer (score 0):

I have been doing this as the following by using [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson)

To save sparseboolean array in SharedPreference:

```
public void SaveSparseBoolean() {
    SparseBooleanArray booleanArray = new SparseBooleanArray();
    SharedPreferences sP;
    sP=context.getSharedPreferences("MY_APPS_PREF",Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sP.edit();
    Gson gson=new Gson();
    editor.putString("Sparse_Array",gson.toJson(booleanArray));
    editor.commit();
}
```

To get the SparsebooleanArray from SharedPreferences

```
public SparseBooleanArray getSparseArray() {
    SparseBooleanArray booleanArray;
    SharedPreferences sP;
    sP = context.getSharedPreferences("MY_APPS_PREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Gson gson=new Gson();
    booleanArray=gson.fromJson(sP.getString("Sparse_Array",""),SparseBooleanArray.class);
    return booleanArray;

}
```